# Rails 4 Issue with ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I have a form partial with the ck editor input given as

**_event_info.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for @event, :url => { :action => "update"} do |f| %>
        <%= f.cktext_area :event_info %>
        <%= f.submit 'submit' %>
     <% end %
```

i am rendering this partial in the show view

**show.html.erb**

```
<%=  link_to "", "#", :id => 'update-click', :class=>"icon fa-edit fa-2x edit-cover", :remote => true %>
          <div id="update-info-show" >
            <%= raw(@event.event_info) %>
          </div>
          <div id="update-info-update" style="display: none">

            </div>

          <input type="button" id="close-editor"  value="Cancel"> </input>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#update-click').click(function() {

        $("#update-info-show").hide();
        $("#update-click").hide();
        $('#update-info-update').show();

        $("#update-info-update").html("<%=j render :partial => 'event_info' %>")

    });
    $('#close-editor').click(function() {
        $('#update-info-update').hide();
        $('#update-click').show();
        $('#update-info-show').show();

    });

</script>
```

so when i click on the #update-click button i get the ck editor properly and after then when i click the cancel button (#close-editor) it hides the editor but when i again click the #update-click button , I don't get the ck editor again instead i get the input plain text area

please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just render partial inside the div and then hide/show

```
    <div id="update-info-update" style="display: none"> 
      <%=render :partial => 'event_info' %>
    </div>
```

And remove

```
    :remote => true
```

from link

Comment: because in my partial i have used ck editor , ck editor is a bit heavy, i have done this so as to load less files when the show page loads , the ck editor only loads when i click the link